# joining two SQL Server querys in to one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

in the database the query is running from there are two tables, one is live, and one is an archive, however i need the data from both added together, here is an example of the query i have.

```
SELECT     SUM(SOPOrderReturnLine.LineTotalValue) AS Value, CONVERT(date, SOPOrderReturnLine.DateTimeCreated) 
                  AS Date
FROM         SOPOrderReturnLine AS SOPOrderReturnLine 
WHERE     (SOPOrderReturnLine.AnalysisCode1 LIKE 'angela%') AND (CONVERT(date, SOPOrderReturnLine.DateTimeCreated) > DATEADD(day, - 15, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, SOPOrderReturnLine.DateTimeCreated)
ORDER BY Date
```

This query sums the data out of the live table, the archive table is the exact same strucute as this but called SOPOrderReturnLineArch, what would be the best way of merging this in to one query, so for the column value would be the sum of both tables for that date instead of just SOPOrderReturnLine  as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL to combine the both tables, then do the rest as before:

```
SELECT     SUM(SOPOrderReturnLine.LineTotalValue) AS Value, CONVERT(date, SOPOrderReturnLine.DateTimeCreated) 
                  AS Date
FROM (SOPOrderReturnLine
      UNION ALL
      SOPOrderReturnLineArch
      ) AS SOPOrderReturnLine 
WHERE     (SOPOrderReturnLine.AnalysisCode1 LIKE 'angela%') AND (CONVERT(date, SOPOrderReturnLine.DateTimeCreated) > DATEADD(day, - 15, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, SOPOrderReturnLine.DateTimeCreated)
ORDER BY Date
```

Or do a UNION ALL with the two results:

```
SELECT     SUM(SOPOrderReturnLine.LineTotalValue) AS Value, CONVERT(date, SOPOrderReturnLine.DateTimeCreated) 
                  AS Date
FROM SOPOrderReturnLine 
WHERE     (SOPOrderReturnLine.AnalysisCode1 LIKE 'angela%') AND (CONVERT(date, SOPOrderReturnLine.DateTimeCreated) > DATEADD(day, - 15, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, SOPOrderReturnLine.DateTimeCreated)
UNION ALL
SELECT     SUM(SOPOrderReturnLine.LineTotalValue) AS Value, CONVERT(date, SOPOrderReturnLine.DateTimeCreated) 
                  AS Date
FROM SOPOrderReturnLineArc AS SOPOrderReturnLine 
WHERE     (SOPOrderReturnLine.AnalysisCode1 LIKE 'angela%') AND (CONVERT(date, SOPOrderReturnLine.DateTimeCreated) > DATEADD(day, - 15, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, SOPOrderReturnLine.DateTimeCreated)
ORDER BY Date
```

Comment: Using this created two rows for each date, if i wanted to add the value for each date together how could i do that? 

400.00 2015-01-15
1145.99 2015-01-15
1498.64 2015-01-16
764.50 2015-01-19
288.11 2015-01-19


this is part of the result so for the 15th i want to add them together and so on if there are multiple lines per day

Comment: Yeah the tables have the exact same structure

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate the results in each table, use `union all` to bring them together, and then re-aggregate:

```
SELECT date, SUM(VALUE) as total_value
FROM ((SELECT CONVERT(date, orl.DateTimeCreated) as date,
              SUM(orl.LineTotalValue) AS Value
       FROM SOPOrderReturnLine AS orl 
       WHERE orl.AnalysisCode1 LIKE 'angela%') AND
             (CONVERT(date, orl.DateTimeCreated) > DATEADD(day, - 15, GETDATE()))
       GROUP BY CONVERT(date, orl.DateTimeCreated)
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT CONVERT(date, orl.DateTimeCreated) as date,
              SUM(orl.LineTotalValue) AS Value
       FROM SOPOrderReturnLine_archive AS orl 
       WHERE orl.AnalysisCode1 LIKE 'angela%') AND
             (CONVERT(date, orl.DateTimeCreated) > DATEADD(day, - 15, GETDATE()))
       GROUP BY CONVERT(date, orl.DateTimeCreated)
      ) 
     ) x
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY Date;
```

Doing the aggregation before the `union all` gives SQL Server more opportunities for optimization.  This isn't *always* faster than doing the aggregation only after the `union all`, but it might be.

Comment: When i'm i run this i get this error Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'SOPOrderReturnLine.DateTimeCreated' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.